# Scraping data from Excel worksheets with different sheet names

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping

I have many excel spreadsheets with data in them. I want to find all excel spreadsheets, go to a specific sheet and find a particular cell. Each spread sheet corresponds to a patient, where one worksheet has the dose the patient received in a particular cell.

Then i can plot the how the value from each spread sheet varies over time.  However, in some workbooks the worksheet is called different things, or is at a different index value. Is there any solution that doesn't involve me manually renaming/moving the 1000+ spreadsheet worksheets i have so they are all in the same format?

This is the code i have that works if they are all at worksheet index 5.

```
#finds all excel files
import os

path = 'C:\Users\malonc01\Desktop\QC' 
files = os.listdir(path)

files_txt = [i for i in files if i.endswith('.xlsx')]
print files_txt

# Gets data from excel files:
import xlrd
Data = []
Time = []

for i in files_txt:
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(str(path) + "\\"  + str(i))
    worksheet1 = workbook.sheet_by_index(5) 
    Data.append(worksheet1.cell_value(10,8))
```

The only two solutions i can think of is:

If you search each worksheet for text in a particular cell (each worksheet is formatted the exact same, just the name/index of the worksheet i want is different). Then use the worksheet that meets this criteria.

or

if the worksheet is called X "or" Y then open it and find the cell value.

Both options i have not been able to find a way to make them work. I hope someone can point me in the right direction to the most simple solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let me suggest a better way to find the Excel files you want to scan -

```
import glob
files = glob.glob("C:\Users\User\Desktop\*.xlsx")
```

As for your question, xlrd gives you a function called sheets(), which returns a list with xlrd Sheet objects.

What you can do is get the list of Excel files, iterate over them, and for each file you can iterate over its sheets and get the data you need.

```
for filename in files:
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(filename )
    for sheet in workbook.sheets():
        Data.append(sheet.cell_value(10,8))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, it really helped and put me down a much better route. Works like a charm now!